# How to extract list of all zones in a CGNS file?

Tags: python-3.x, cgns

I am trying to use "PyCGNS" python package in conda to extract the list of all the "zones" in a CGNS file. Attached is the snapshot view of the opened file.

Here is what I want:

```
zone_list = [zone1, zone2, ..., zone51]
```

I would appreciate your help.[image: .cgns]

---

Hint:

Here is the print(tree) value:

```
['CGNSTree', None, [['CGNSLibraryVersion', array([3.21], dtype=float32), [], 'CGNSLibraryVersion_t'], ['Base', array([3, 3]), [['zone41', array([[ 77,  76,   0],
       [113, 112,   0],
       [ 49,  48,   0]], dtype=int64), [['ZoneType', array([b'S', b't', b'r', b'u', b'c', b't', b'u', b'r', b'e', b'd'],
      dtype='|S1'), [], 'ZoneType_t'], ['GridCoordinates', None, [['CoordinateX', array(....
```

Comment: You have tagged your question with both `cgns` and `h5py` tags and mention `pycgns` in the body. Which package do you want to use to read your file? If PyCGNS, have you read the [Introduction in the PyCGNS documentation](https://pycgns.github.io/introduction.html) ? Also, did you create the image with NAV, the Navigator? Note: is too small to read (at least for me).

Comment: Hi, yes I opened it using NAV but I cannot take a clearer snapshot of the family tree structure of the file. Let me try a different way! Also, the h5py installation had issue and I am giving up on that. So, I really want to utilize pycgns to read the file. I have gone through that documentation you mentioned but still not learned how to extract specific nodes from such a structure as it seems the structure of my file is not very typical.  (I am removing h5py then)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a PyCGNS guy, but I understand HDF5 data schema, so will give it a try. :)

The docs recommend `(tree,links,paths)=CGNS.MAP.load("your.hdf")` Did you try that? It returns `tree` which is a Python list with the CGNS tree info. As I understand, the tree describes the node structure (aka schema). Per the documentation, the node structure looks like this:

| Attribute | type |
| --- | --- |
| Name | string |
| Value | numpy array |
| Children | list of CGNS/Python nodes |
| Type | string |

You could `print(tree)`, but I think you will be swamped with output. You can interrogate the tree to find nodes named "zone*". Based on your image, I suspect all zone nodes are all children of a Node with named "Base". If so, the code will look something like this (educated guess):

```
import CGNS.MAP
(tree,links,paths) = CGNS.MAP.load("your.hdf")
# print(f'Tree has {len(tree[2])} child nodes')
level_1_nodes = tree[2]
# print(f'Level 1 Node List has {len(level_1_nodes)} child nodes') 
base_node = level_1_nodes[1]
# print(f'Base Node List has {len(base_node[2])} child nodes') 
zone_nodes = base_node[2]
print(f'Zone Node List has {len(zone_nodes)} child nodes') 
zones = [] 
for zone in zone_nodes:
    print(f'Checking on child node: {zone[0]}')
    if 'zone' in zone[0]:
        # print(f'Zone: {zone[0]} node has {len(zone[2])} child nodes') 
        zones.append(zone[0])
```

If you are familiar with List Comprehension, the last 4 lines can be simplified to:

```
zones = [ z[0] for z in zone_nodes if "zone" in z[0] ]
```

Give that a try and see if solves your problem. If it's not exactly right, it should get you close.

Comment: Thank you very much, here is the error message I receive right after this line if node[0] == "Base"                    "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: That's strange. That implies `tree` is `None` (and not a list of nodes). I assume you modified `CGNS.MAP.load()` - replacing my filename with YOUR HDF filename. Also, you need to run in the directory/folder with the file, or provide the complete path. After that, it's hard to diagnose without some real data.  What do you get if you `print(tree)` after line 2? You should see a TON of output.

Comment: Just posted that as a hint to the question.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see it...looks like `tree` is slightly more complicated that I assumed (looks like a list of lists of lists - Ugh). LOL I need to tinker with it to see how to unwind them to get to `BASE` and `zone##`. Not hard, just tedious.

Comment: Alright. I used your example tree to figure out the structure. The nested lists of child nodes (which are also lists) gets kinda hairy. Code updated, and 99% sure it will work. I included some extra print statements (commented out). Uncomment them if you want to see details about the child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I was finally looking for (thank for the help from kcw78)

```
def zone_extractor(fname: str) -> List:
    """This function extracts all the zones in a CGNS file

    Args:
        fname (str): _description_

    Returns:
        List: _description_
    """
    (tree, links, paths) = CGM.load(Path(FILE_DIR) / fname)
    zones = []
    for node in tree:
        if (node is not None) and isinstance(node, list) and (node[1][0] == 'Base'):
            zones = [child[0] for child in node[1][2] if child[0].startswith('zone')]
    return sorted_nicely(zones)
```